# Many queries showing in mysql - "Copying to tmp table"

Tags: mysql, database

I am getting too much of "Copying to tmp table" in mysql for certain select queries.

What parameters should i look into ? Tables are both myisam and innodb.

Comment: Can you please provide an example query that is causing this issue.

Comment: Some help for self help: have you tried EXPLAIN on your queries? More often than not this helps you to identify the bottlenecks yourself quickly.

Comment: could you please add `explain` and `create table`